# what parameter adjust can make the disparity result correctly? using cv2.StereoBM in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjWSI.jpg)   [left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcHif.jpg)   [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM63F.jpg)

```
   import numpy as np
   import cv2

   imgL = cv2.imread("C:/Users/admin/jupyter/car/challenge_pictrue/right/right2.jpg ",0)
   imgR = cv2.imread("C:/Users/admin/jupyter/car/challenge_pictrue/left/left2.jpg ",0)

   cv2.imshow('imgL', imgL)
   cv2.imshow('imgR', imgR)

   stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=17)
   disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)
   disparity = cv2.normalize(disparity, disparity, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, 
   dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
   cv2.imshow('disparity', disparity)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

"What's parameter should i adjust can make the result correctly?"

Comment: What is wrong with the result?  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I can't see any obstacle clearly. So i think it's wrong.

Comment: What have you tried changing in the parameters for StereoBM_create? Have you tried using larger values for blockSize? See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/dba/classcv_1_1StereoBM.html#a04fdf00525f82fe708d556e2cd359004

Comment: This paper's result is all i want.  [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7312630). Yes i try to change blockSize, but the car's signal will disappear. Actually, i just want to see any obstacle,not air and road.

Comment: I think you need to swap the files you have in imgL and imgR. You have right2 assigned to imgL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong method. BM is only meant for simple indoor use with low dynamic measuring range. With indoor image, you just need a adjsut mindisp and number of disp and window size.

For outdoor, it is more complex. Maybe u just start. BM and other global based method has the poor result. Either disfigured for overfitting, or streaking effect due to local similarity error.

Current state of the art for traditional CV is the SGM based method proposed by HH. And for the deep learning-based method, there is no best case, vary from case to case/dataset to dataset. The work from lecun Žbontar "Stereo Matching by Training a Convolutional Neural Network " is sth that I used for comparison often.

[image]

Try not to use too cheap/low complexity algorithms for advanced tasks. And also if you use it for actual driving action control( because I saw you other Vdispary problem), you will get yourself killed. I've tested this in various locations. It not the right way. Grab a LIDAR or other active ranging for extra safety

This is mine results using census with SGM. you can refer to this link
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html for reproducing.

[image]

The white dots denotes the close object. by Vdispaity, it will say there is close by object when there are none. Thus it will cause car to suddenly stop.  You can refer to my thesis at NTU for how to remove them. And remember to cite them properly

[image]

Regards

Dr Yuan Shenghai

Comment: Dear Yuan Shenghai, Your mean  if i use it for actual driving action control, i will get myself killed. What a shocking sentence for me. Do you mean that the current algorithm can not get good cutting information in the rapidly changing image information? Or is some high-brightness information will make the computer misjudge that there is an obstacle approaching?

Comment: stereo alone is not stable. try to add some other active sensing device. currently those autonomous car kill accident are all from vision only navigation, uber(didn't run lidar) , tesla(repeated offender).  vision based naigation is a lot more complex than just stereo. stereo provide only depth cue, there are a lot more clue to refine scene depth such as motion parallax, object perspective transform(which generated from semanic knowledge). It way too complex

Comment: for uber kill case, they ignore those small white dot(close object) because they think it is false positive. so i think you should understand what i mean.  ref: https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/268915-fatal-arizona-crash-ubercar-saw-woman-called-it-a-false-positive#:~:text=Fatal%20Arizona%20Crash%3A%20Uber%20Car%20Saw%20Woman,Called%20It%20a%20False%20Positive&text=The%20Uber%20self%2Ddriving%20car,with%20the%20car's%20multiple%20sensors.&text=In%20other%20words%2C%20the%20car's,car%20considered%20a%20false%20positive.